# "this application is unconfined. It can access all personal files and system resources"

Tags: permissions

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and I can't download any app from the store. 
Every time up to 15%, it'll stop with this sentence popping out. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are they snaps?  If so I believe this is just a warning.  Read up on unconfined snaps and see what they are all about.  Then you can decide if they are worth installing.

Comment: With the message does it give you an option to proceed or cancel? Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760803/security-of-snaps-under-x11

Comment: @rkeating, thanks! It is snaps but there is no options for me to install or not unfortunately.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, Thank o! NO, there is no option to cancel or proceed. And I went through the link that you provided but there is no solution for my situation.

Comment: What apps are giving you this message?  When I get a chance I will try and install them on a VM.